# Unparseable Date Exception SimpleDateFormat for Hmm format

Tags: java, simpledateformat, datetime-format, date-format, time-format

While validating the given string text is of **Hmm format** getting this error

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1637"

but this is working for text "747".

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

    public class Validation{
    
         public void validateDateFormat(String format,String text){
              SimpleDateFormat sdfrmt = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
              sdfrmt.setLenient(false);
              Date testDate = null;
              try {
                    testDate = sdfrmt.parse(text);
    
              } catch (ParseException e) {
                    System.out.println("dateFormat Exception :");
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
         
         public static void main(String []args){
            Validation val = new Validation();
            val.validateDateFormat("Hmm","747"); //working 
            val.validateDateFormat("Hmm","1637");//not working
         }
    }
```

This is for validating the given columns from the uploaded file.So wrote this to be dynamic based on the format written in the config for each column.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, for they are obsolete and troublesome. You know why? [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). Use classes from the `java.time` package instead.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, it *should* work.

But you should use the newer Java Date and Time API (JSR 310) available in the `java.time` package.

If you then replace `Date` with `LocalTime`, `SimpleDateFormat` with `DateTimeFormatter` (using the `ofPattern` factory method) and `ParseException` with `DateTimeParseException`, [it'll work](https://ideone.com/1q6Xxm).

Comment: Great link! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the `SimpleDateFormat` is unable to parse the given date using the format you have given.

Let's understand - your format is `Hmm` and you have given the date as `747` then, of course during parsing, the first letter `7` of the date is mapped to the first letter "H" of the format i.e. hours and `47` is mapped to `mm` i.e. minutes and hence it is able to convert correctly but for the next date `1637` it is failing because it does not know which letter to assign to `H`.

Here are some options you can try to make it more generic, choose format such as `HHmm` and always give the date of length 4, for e.g. for `747` enter the input as `0747` and it should work.

Or choose a format that is more clear for the parser to map for e.g. you can choose the format as `H:mm` and give the inputs as `7:47` or `16:37` since there is a delimiter `:` between hours and minutes, the parser will be able to parse all types of time irrespective of the length of the given input 3 or 4.